# Indexing PDF file in ElasticSearch using Java Code

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to Index PDF files in elastic search 6.3.2 using Java code. So far I have written following code to save the pdf in ES. The code is working fine and I am able to save the Base64 encoded string of my PDF in ES. I want to understand if the approach which I am following is correct or not? Is there any better way of doing it?
Following is my code:

```
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("mypdf.pdf"));
        try {
            byte[]  fileByteStream = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream );
            String base64String = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(fileByteStream).getBytes(),"UTF-8");
            String strEncoded = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString( base64String.getBytes( "utf-8" ));
            this.stream.close();

                    JSONObject correspondenceNode = new JSONObject(); 
                    correspondenceNode.put("data",strEncoded );

                    String strSsonValues = correspondenceNode.toString();
                    HttpEntity entity = new NStringEntity(strSsonValues , ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
                    elasticrestClient.put("/2018/documents/"1, entity);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Basically what I am doing here is, I am converting the PDF document into Base64String and saving it into ES and while reading, I am converting it back.

following is the code for decoding:

```
String responseBody = elasticrestClient.get("/2018/documents/1");
//some code to fetch the hits
JSONObject h = hitsArray.getJSONObject(0);
source = h.getJSONObject("_source");
String object = (source.getString("data"));
byte[] decodedStr = Base64.getDecoder().decode( object );

FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("download.pdf");
fos.write(Base64.getDecoder().decode(new String( decodedStr, "utf-8" )));
fos.close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be correct to store a BASE64 content in elasticsearch but few pieces might be missing here:

1. You are not "indexing" the PDF as per say in Elasticsearch. If you want to do so, you need to define an [ingest pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/ingest.html) and use the [ingest attachment plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/6.3/ingest-attachment.html) to extract the content from the PDF.
2. You did not speak about the mapping you are using. If you "really" want to keep the binary content around, you might want to define the BASE64 field as a [binary data type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/binary.html).
3. It does not sound to me a good idea to use elasticsearch to store large blobs like this.

Instead, I'd extract text and metadata and index that + an URL to the binary itself. Like:

```
{
  "content": "Extracted text here",
  "meta": {
    // Meta data there
  },
  "url": "file://path/to/file"
}
```

You can also look at [FSCrawler](https://github.com/dadoonet/fscrawler) (including its code) which does basically that.

Comment: I do not want to do full text search on the PDF. I just want to save and retrieve it based of other properties. I wan just wondering if there is any other alternative to what I was doing.

Comment: Then don't forget to mark it as a binary in the mapping as I wrote. But again, I'd not recommend storing big PDF files in elasticsearch. May be few kilobytes is ok but I'd avoid storing megabytes of documents. Using a storage system like CouchDB, MapR, HDFS, S3... Would be a better solution. But try it with Elasticsearch if it works for you...

Comment: Yes. The property which is holding the base64 value have type "type": "binary".
The average document size which we have is about 60~90 KB.

Currently we are saving our documents in JCR Repository, but now we want to move to some other solution, that's why I am evaluating ES to check if it can serve my purpose.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/resiliency/current/index.html  is a good read.